# How to Use make to compile c file on codespace

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cs50, codespaces

[image: Codespace for c, cs50 course]

make CLI keyword is failing to compile my c programming file.

Comment: `make` is not a cli keyword.  It is a program which must be installed.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be 2 different issues there:

1- `make` seems to not be present in your workspace. Please try running `rebuild50` to rebuild it. You'll not lose your files.

2- You're issueing the command from outside the correct folder.

Please note that in `hello` folder there are two distinct files (`hello` and `hello.c`), but the output from your `ls` command shows only one result (which is the folder, not the files).

Please run `cd hello` first to get into the folder containing the file to make.